# C++ Overloading | (bitwise OR) operator that returns constant value

Tags: c++

I would like to use operator '|' in a following manner:

```
    switch(color){
        case Color::Red | Color::Green:
        ...
```

The problem is that the operator must return constant value, but I cannot make it work. I tried something like this:

```
    template<class T> inline const T operator| (T a, T b){ return const (T)((int)a | (int)b); }
```

but it doesn't do the job.

Comment: try `template<class T> inline constexpr const T operator| (const T a, const T b){ return const (T)((int)a | (int)b);}`

Comment: Also your subject is kind of misleading. Are you trying to use a logical OR or bitwise OR? The `||` operator is the former, `|` is the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`case` should use constant expression, i.e. compile-time constant. Mark your operator as `constexpr`:

```
template<class T> inline constexpr T operator| (T a, T b){ return (T)((int)a | (int)b); }
```